# Searching for all possible orders of an element in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to find all possible orders of the element α in the ring F3[α], where α^4 = α + 2.
Should i search for all possible orders of divisors of 3^4-1, then exponentiate α to a power equal to the divisors and check if the result equals 1?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Not so fast. May be $x^4-x-2$ is not irreducible?